# Importing namespaces in _ViewImports.cshtml

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on .Net project and I'm using *_ViewImports.cshtml* file to import namespaces for many *ViewModels* I have. Similar to what is described at [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout#importing-shared-directives).
Is there a way to import just parent namespace e.g. `@using WebApplication1.ViewModels` and have access to it's view models in razor view:

- `@model Home.HomepageViewModel` or
- `@model About.AboutViewModel`

So far I did not manage to do it and I have a really long list of namespaces in my _ViewImports.cshtml file (don't mind much, but would be nice if possible to do just import of e.g. WebApplication1.ViewModels and have access to it's view models).

Tnx!

Comment: have you tried doing the way you are asking?

Comment: yes and it did not work for me.

Comment: If this is default feature, not sure then why I can't do it (namespaces are not recognized in my razor views).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor is not that smart to understand that kind of "partial" namespaces for models.
If you define `@using App.ViewModels` in ViewImports, and your actual view model is in `App.ViewModels.Home.HomeVM`, then you can not use `@model Home.HomeVM` (omit App.ViewModels), Razor can't figure out it is part of `App.ViewModels` namespace (prefix model namespace).

I'm guessing that's because Razor can't know what prefix to use, you can have 50 @usings in ViewImports and Razor would have to go through each of them, and then if you have same class name if different namespaces, can't know which one to use ...

You have to have full paths in _ViewImports file, or full path in the view.

Comment: So 50 @usings it is. Tnx!